# How can i call a method in my fragment from my activity?

Tags: android

Theoretically, lets say i have two classes with corresponding XML files - Activity and Frag

Activity.java

```
    public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Fragment fragment = new Frag();
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragmentArea, fragment);
        ft.commit();

       }
    }
```

Frag.java

```
    public class Frag extends Fragment {


    private TextView txtView;

    public Frag() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_, container, false);
        txtView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        return view;
    }

    public void setTextView(String str) {
        txtView.setText(str);
        }

    }
```

activity xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.eksamen.chris.eksempelfragment.Activity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/fragmentArea">
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Fragment xml

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.eksamen.chris.eksempelfragment.Frag">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Fragment"
        android:id="@+id/textView"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

As you can see, i have the method setTextView() in my Frag class. Obviously enough, what i would like to do is to call that method from my Activity class.

I have tried grasping this for some hours now, and i really cannot figure out a way to do this. Every example/tutorial out there makes my app crash.

Could someone explain to me how this works, taken the example we have in hand into consideration? Or maybe there is a better way to provide the fragment with data from my activity?

I'd be grateful!

Edit: awful indentation, had some issues, trying to fix.

Comment: At which point (in the Activity) would you like to set the text of the Fragment's TextView?

Comment: Good point, i should have incorporated that in my example. But does it really matter where i do it though? For example, in a method in my Activity which instanciates another class and recieves a value from that class, and sets the TextView value in the fragment.

Comment: Well you can do that in the fragment itself!! @ImStupid

Comment: It does matter because you asked for alternatives. But I think you are looking for a way to pass a String to the Fragment so the TextView can show the String if (as soon as) the TextView is not null. Is this correct?

Comment: @SantanuSur Well, someone told me i should keep fragments mostly logic free and implement that logic elsewhere.

Comment: lel :p who is the sum1 ?? he misguided you ..anyway you can pass it to the constructor of your fragment and then begin the fragment transaction... @ImStupid

Comment: @0X0nosugar Yes, thats correct.

Comment: @ImStupid you should keep your **mainUI thread** logic free..but you can start the background threads from both activity and fragment..

Comment: @SantanuSur Hmm ok maybe i will try to do this, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to pass data from Activity to Fragment , you have to use :

**Bundle**

which is a KEY VALUE data structure for passing values between fragments and activity so at your onCreate() in Activity class will be

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String str = "your_string_here";
    // 1 - 
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    // 2 -
    bundle.putString("KEY", str);
    Fragment fragment = new Frag();
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    // 3 -
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);  
    ft.replace(R.id.fragmentArea, fragment);
    ft.commit(); }
```

and at your fragment

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_, container, false);
    txtView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    // 4 - NOTE : Should hould the same key at the Activity class :
    String str = getArguments().getString("KEY");
    setTextView(str);
    return view;
}
```